# Hibernate select lowest value greater than

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to get hibernate to return an object that has the lowest ID number that is greater than a certain value.

The code I have is returning an integer though, instead of the object.

**Code**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Story.class);
Criterion storyId = Restrictions.ge("id", 2);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.min("id"));
criteria.add(storyId);
criteria.setProjection(projList);
List<?> storyResult = criteria.list();
session.close();            
Story story = (Story) storyResult.get(0);
```

Right now this is returning "3" as an integer. 3 is the next available ID, but why is hibernate giving me back an integer instead of the object?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are telling it to so (`Projections.min("id")`). BTW Integer is an Object.

Comment: Thanks Orid. I have taken the integer thats returned and use that to pull out the correct story object from the database. Seems quite inefficient though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a Projection, you are essentially asking Hibernate to change your query from `SELECT * FROM TABLE` to a `SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TABLE` query. That's one of the features of a projection.

To achieve what you actually want to achieve, you need to use the projection to get the ID and then use another query to retrieve the object.

```
Criteria idQuery = session.createCriteria(Story.class);
idQuery.add(Restrictions.ge("id", 2));
idQuery.setProjection(Projections.min("id"));
int returnedId = criteria.uniqueResult();

Criteria storyQuery = session.createCriteria(Story.class);
storyQuery.add(Restrictions.idEq(returnedId);
Story story = (Story) storyQuery.uniqueResult();
return story;
```